# Swiftのプロトコル準拠について(Javaなどの未詳細クラスなど)

Tags: swift, swift3

こんにちは。
つかぬ事をお聞きしてしまうのですが、protocolの実装について方法が分からなくて困っています。
どなたか回答いただけたら幸いです。

---

1つのViewControllerにcontainerViewなどの都合で複数のViewControllerをプロパティで持たせていて(viewControllersという配列)その複数のViewControllerにはtableViewを必ず1つ持たせようと思います。

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    if let firstVC = viewControllers[currentIndex] as? FirstViewController {
        firstVC.tableView.isEditing = editing
    }
    if let secondVC = viewControllers[currentIndex] as? SecondViewController {
        secondVC.tableView.isEditing = editing
    }
    if let thirdVC = viewControllers[currentIndex] as? ThirdViewController {
        thirdVC.tableView.isEditing = editing
    }
}
```

このように1つ1つダウンキャストして判定するのも良いのですが少し単調な気がします。

配列の中のViewController達の親としてtableViewを持つようなUIViewControllerクラスが欲しいところなのですが
Swift言語でプロトコルを用いて良い感じに実装するにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか...?

Answer (score 1):

「良い感じ」になっているかどうかは、かなり怪しい気がしますが、「Swift言語でプロトコルを用いて」と言う部分だけを取らせてもらうと、こんな感じになるでしょうか。

```
protocol HavingTableView {
    var tableView: UITableView! {get}
}
extension FirstViewController: HavingTableView {}
extension SecondViewController: HavingTableView {}
extension ThirdViewController: HavingTableView {}

//...
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        if let tableViewVC = viewControllers[currentIndex] as? HavingTableView {
            tableViewVC.tableView.isEditing = editing
        }
    }
```

現在のSwiftではクラスとプロトコルを組み合わせて、`UIViewController & HavingTableView`のようなデータ型を作ることができないので、`viewControllers`は`[UIViewController]`としておく想定です。そうすると`as? HavingTableView`のようなキャストも必要になるし、あまり「良い感じ」には見えないかもしれません。

---

「配列の中のViewController達の親としてtableViewを持つようなUIViewControllerクラスが欲しい」と言うのであれば、そのままそれを共通の親クラスとして定義してしまうという手もありますが。

```
class MyBaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView!
}
class FirstViewController: MyBaseViewController {
    //...
}
class SecondViewController: MyBaseViewController {
    //...
}
class ThirdViewController: MyBaseViewController {
    //...
}

//...        
    var viewControllers: [MyBaseViewController] = []

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        viewControllers[currentIndex].tableView.isEditing = editing
    }
```

私的にはこちらの方が「良い感じ」に思えるのですが、`tableView`を`@IBOutlet`にしたいのなら、ちょっと面倒かもしれません。

Comment: OOPerさん回答ありがとうございます。
「いい感じ」という曖昧な表現申し訳御座いませんでした。
http://qiita.com/SatoshiN21/items/92aa1529f35b674c72dd
等のプロトコル指向が気になっていました。
開発途中に思った疑問だったので、つい先走って質問をしてしまいました。回答頂いたものを参考にして勉強していきたいと思います
ありがとうございました。